# Google Sheets - Historical Data not returning yesterday

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

The formula below is been used to get the historical data until today:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","ALL",DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1,1,1),"12/05/2019","DAILY")
```

Unfortunately I don't receive today's data (until here ok, I understand why), but yesterday's data isn't passed too.

I just receive the data until 2019-12-03.

Remembering: the question was open at 2019-12-05.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Sometime during the day, yesterday's data suddenly appeared. What I did was adding the current price to the bottom like this:

```
={GOOGLEFINANCE(A1,"price",date(year(A3),MONTH(A3),DAY(A3)),TODAY(),"daily");TODAY(),GOOGLEFINANCE(A1)}
```

Where A1 is the ticker, and A3 is a start date.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that both the time zone as well as the time pulling your request, are variables affecting your results.

As mentioned under `GOOGLEFINANCE` [documentation page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en):

- `end_date|num_days` - [ OPTIONAL ] - **The end date when fetching historical data, or the number of days from start_date for which to return data.**
- Quotes are not sourced from all markets and **may be delayed up to 20 minutes**.
- **Dates passed into `GOOGLEFINANCE` are treated as noon UTC time. Exchanges that close before that time may be shifted by a day.**

**As an example**: taking into account the above quotes as well as that there is a **[time difference](http://www.timebie.com/timezone/brazilnewyork.php) with Brazil (UTC -2)** the results you get would be the expected ones.

*Extra: Not even changing your time zone under `Spreadsheet settings` will make any difference (as others tried before).*